# What are the command line parameters (options) for Microsoft's CMTRACE tool?

Tags: windows, command-line, logging, tail, parameters

The CMTRACE tool is included in Microsoft's [System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=50012).

It's a reasonably good `tail` tool.  One of its downsides, however, is that it can take a *very* long time to open a large log file (many minutes).  A workaround for this issue is to select the `Ignore existing lines` option when opening a file.  That works fine when opening a log file via the `Open` dialog box, but I'm looking for a way to selectively enable that option from the Windows command prompt (or a batch file).

I've searched for the command line parameters for CMTRACE, but all searches are coming up nil.

What are the command line parameters (options) for Microsoft's CMTRACE tool?

Comment: Have you tried `cmtrace /help`, cmtrace /?` etc?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this myself. While I can find no command line parameters, it seems like CMTrace keeps its settings in the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Trace32`.

One value is named "Ignore Existing Lines". Seems this sets it across the user, but so does checking the box in any CMTrace session. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a good observation.  Thanks Chrissy!